# XML parsing failure - [s4s-elt-invalid-content.1]

Tags: xml, parsing, xsd

I'm having problems while parsing a XML file. The XML schema used is:

```
<xsd:complexType name="QuoteFIBondPrice">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="BidPrice" type="QuoteFIBondValue" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="MidPrice" type="QuoteFIBondValue" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="OfferPrice" type="QuoteFIBondValue" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="MaturityDate" type="DbGMLType:SystemName" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="Coupon" type="DbGMLType:SystemName" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xsd:element name="DisplayName" type="DbGMLType:SystemName" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="QuoteFIBondValue">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="QuoteValue" type="DbGMLType:QuoteValue" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The error message I'm getting is this:

**class com.db.dbadapter.util.xml.XMLValidatorParserException: SAXParseException(s) encountered: 
[s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'QuoteFIBondPrice' is invalid.  Element 'sequence' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often. (line: 53, column: 18) ]**

Could you please give me a hand?

I've changed the XML schema and now it is this way:

```
<xsd:complexType name="QuoteFIBondPrice">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="BidPrice" type="QuoteFIBondValue" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="MidPrice" type="QuoteFIBondValue" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="OfferPrice" type="QuoteFIBondValue" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="MaturityDate" type="DbGMLType:SystemName" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="Coupon" type="DbGMLType:SystemName" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="DisplayName" type="DbGMLType:SystemName" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="QuoteFIBondValue">
    <xsd:all>
        <xsd:element name="QuoteValue" type="DbGMLType:QuoteValue" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:all>
</xsd:complexType>
```

After testing, I realised that the previous error has changed to:

**[cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'BidPrice'. One of '{MaturityDate, Coupon, DisplayName}' is expected. (line: 35, column: 17) ]

[cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'BidPrice' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only. (line: 35, column: 35) ]

[cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'MidPrice' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only. (line: 36, column: 38) ]class com.db.dbadapter.util.xml.XMLValidatorParserException: SAXParseException(s) encountered:

[cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'OfferPrice' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only. (line: 34, column: 39) ]

[cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'BidPrice'. One of '{MaturityDate, Coupon, DisplayName}' is expected. (line: 35, column: 17) ]

[cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'BidPrice' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only. (line: 35, column: 35) ]

[cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'MidPrice' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only. (line: 36, column: 38) ]**

@Jon, @skaffman, do you have any suggestion?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `complexContent` element, I don't think, you can just put the `sequence` directly under the `complexType`:

```
<xsd:complexType name="QuoteFIBondPrice">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="BidPrice" type="QuoteFIBondValue" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="MidPrice" type="QuoteFIBondValue" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="OfferPrice" type="QuoteFIBondValue" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="MaturityDate" type="DbGMLType:SystemName" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="Coupon" type="DbGMLType:SystemName" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="DisplayName" type="DbGMLType:SystemName" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

See [w3schools docs and examples](http://www.w3schools.com/Schema/el_complextype.asp).

Comment: Hi skaffman. Ok, I'll remove the "complexContent" element. But will I need to remove the "sequence" element as well? Thanks

Comment: Nice. I'll correct and make a try. I'll let you know when I have finished. Thank you very much

Comment: Hi skaffman, I've edited my question. Unfortunately the error has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's the schema that's invalid, not the message itself. `complexContent` is meant to contain annotations, restrictions or extensions.

Are you sure it's not meant to be just `complexType` instead of having a nested `complexContent`?

Comment: Hi Jon. In fact I'm a newbie to XML schemas. You mean I must remove the "complexContent" element? Thanks

Comment: @John: Yes, remove the element but not its contents... see skaffman's answer, basically :)

Comment: Hi Jon, I've edited my question. Unfortunately the error has changed.

Comment: @John: Okay, so now it looks like the schema is valid, but the content doesn't match the schema...

Comment: The error says "Element 'BidPrice' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only." I'm trying to figure out the meaning of this message. I think the XML message may be coming on this format:

<BidPrice> <another_element> value </another_element> </BidPrice>

And in fact it should come on this format:

<BidPrice> value </BidPrice>

But I'm not sure...

Comment: @John: Yes, that looks like it's probably the problem. You should *definitely* log a copy of the XML so you can try this in a more controlled way.